# File to MultipartFile throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, file, spring-boot, file-upload, multipart

Commons-fileupload

```
    <!-- File Upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am trying to convert file to MultipartFile

```
 Line#1 ) File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Foo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ErrorFile-1538475847143.csv");
 Line#2 ) FileItem fileItem = new DiskFileItem("file", "text/csv", false, file.getName(), (int) file.length(), file.getParentFile());
 Line#3 ) MultipartFile multipartFile = new CommonsMultipartFile(fileItem);
```

But Line#2 throwing exception

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.toString()
```

any resolution ?

Comment: Can you extract all the method calls from the `DiskFileItem` constructor into variables? Then we would know which one is null.

Comment: Your code works fine for me..Are you sure you posted all relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

This resolved my issue:

```
fileItem.getOutputStream();
```